# How to declare friend with static function in Outer class inside the Inner class?

Tags: c++

Here is the simple code:

```
class Outer
{
public:
    class Inner
    {
        static friend void Outer::s_foo(Inner*); //<-- How to declare that?
    private:
        void inner_foo() {}
    };

    static void s_foo(Inner * inner)
    {
        inner->inner_foo();
    }
};
```

Is it possible to declare friendship correctly?

Comment: I personally see little point in not befriending the whole nesting class.

Comment: Just a caution about terminology: Java has a formal notion of "outer" and "inner" classes. C++ does not. So don't expect a **nested** class to act like a Java "inner" class.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where order is important. To know `s_foo` exists, the `friend` declaration must come after `s_foo`

```
class Outer
{
public:
    class Inner; // forward declaration to satisfy s_foo's argument

    static void s_foo(Inner * inner) // moved ahead of friend declaration
    {
        inner->inner_foo();
    }
    class Inner
    {
        friend void Outer::s_foo(Inner*); //No need for static here. Just need the name
    private:
        void inner_foo() {}
    };
};
```

As for why `s_foo` can see `inner_foo` even though it is declared later, That's just C++ being friendly. When resolving the methods C++ considers the whole class. Why it can't do the same for the `friend` declaration, frankly I don't know.

Comment: I found the case when compiled with clang, GCC. But not compiled with MSVC compillers. Is it bug? Here is the code: https://godbolt.org/z/YEjMdaYTb

Comment: @nen777w I've never tried a `friend` to a parameter pack before. I don't know the quirks there, so I can't dash something off as a comment, but surely someone here at SO does. I'd google up *friend to a parameter pack* to see if there's already an answer; otherwise, you've got a good new question there.

Comment: Side note: Use `/std:c++17` to specify C++17 support in Visual Studio.